# how to copy text from column of active sheet and past it to another sheet according to the specific row and column number which are in active sheet

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I am new to excel vba. I want to write a macro which can copy text value of a column A of active sheet from first row to last row and past it to another sheet of same wordbook. But the complex part is that I have to paste these text according to specific row and column number which are given in active sheet in column B and C.

This is an example of my data in active sheet:

```
    column A    column B     column C            
   text value      row       column
        aaaa        1         1  
        aaaa        1         2  
        bbbb        1         3  
        bbbb        1         4
        cccc        1         5
        cccc        1         6
        dddd        2         1
        dddd        2         2
        dddd        2         3
        eeee        2         4
        eeee        2         5
        ffff        2         6
```

and so on.

The result sheet  should be:

```
    column A   column B    column C   column D    column E   column F  ..... 
1   aaaa        aaaa        bbbb        bbbb       cccc        cccc
2   dddd        dddd        dddd        eeee       eeee        ffff
3
4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you.

```
Option Explicit
Sub copy_rng()
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim lrow As Long
    Dim myArray() As Variant
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws1 = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set ws2 = wb.Sheets("Sheet2")

    lrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    myArray() = ws1.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lrow, 3)).Value
    ws2.Activate
    For i = 1 To UBound(myArray)
        Cells(myArray(i, 2), myArray(i, 3)).Value2 = myArray(i, 1)
        If myArray(i, 4) = 1 Then
            Cells(myArray(i, 2), myArray(i, 3)).Interior.ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent1 'blue
        ElseIf myArray(i, 4) = 2 Then
            Cells(myArray(i, 2), myArray(i, 3)).Interior.ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent2 'red
        ElseIf myArray(i, 4) = 3 Then
            Cells(myArray(i, 2), myArray(i, 3)).Interior.ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent3 'green
        ElseIf myArray(i, 4) = 4 Then
            Cells(myArray(i, 2), myArray(i, 3)).Interior.ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent6 'orange
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

You can create an array with the data from worksheet 1, and then use the row and column number from the array to copy the data from column A into the correct cells.

Comment: its working.thanks a lot.I have another question.If there is values in column D of text in column A in sheet1. According to value I want assign color from white to red( 0 to higher ) and past it into result sheet(sheet2) as a cell background with text according to row and column. could you please help  me?

Comment: its working.thanks a lot.I have another question.If there is values in column D of text in column A in sheet1. According to value I want assign color from white to red( 0 to higher ) and past it into result sheet(sheet2) as a cell background with text according to row and column. could you please help me? @vockz

Comment: I've amended my original answer to incorporate changing the cells colours too. I'm not sure how you would do it aside from using an If statement like I have, there may be a more efficient way. You will have to find out what the colours you want to use "xlThemeColorAccent" number is. Hope that works for you.